# How can I make a global header rather than pasting it in each page?

Tags: html

Every time I update my header, I go in and update each page individually. I'm pretty sure there is a way to keep the header in one file and just call it within each page.

This way I update one file and it's updated on each page automatically. I'm new in all this, so please keep it simple to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which server you are using to host the files - but most of them have the ability to do server-side includes.  This would let you put your header into a separate file, and 'include' it in each html file.  When the HTML file is requested, the server would replace the include statement with the contents of the header file.

Check your server documentation for more details

Answer (score 0):

If your web host supports php, this is very very easy to do..

First create your header.php file and insert all the text, buttons and so forth in the header.php file.

Second create a footer.php file and insert all the text, buttons and so forth in the footer.php file.

Then create a index.php and call the include files like this.

```
<div><?php include 'header.php'; ?></div>
<div>Sone Content</div>
<div><?php include 'footer.php'; ?></div>
```

Then for the other pages follow the same guidlines. In order for this to work all of your files need to have a .php extension.

Answer (score 0):

With `seamless` attribute your `iframe` tag would seems like part of your document:

```
<iframe src="header.htm" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
```

or

```
<iframe src="header.htm" seamless></iframe>
```

Just be careful about the browser support!